# Need complete event in model.valueChanges

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a directive as below

```
@Directive({
selector: '[debounce]'
})
export class DebounceDirective {
@Output()
public onchange = new EventEmitter<any>();

@Input('debounce')
public debounceTime: number = 500;

private isFirstChange: boolean = true;

constructor(public model: NgControl) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.model.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(this.debounceTime)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(event => {
            debugger;
            if (this.isFirstChange) {
                this.isFirstChange = false;
            } else {
                this.onchange.emit(event);
            }
        });
  }
}
```

Html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="admin.Name" [debounce]="500" (onchange)="updateField($event)" />
```

When event gets fired i only get the value of input, but i need the whole event here.In subscribe i want the complete event. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

The `valueChanges` Observable emits only the value of the input field. Not the entire event object.

Maybe you can pass an instance of [`FormControl` instead](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html) and then register a [`registerOnChange` function](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html#!#registerOnChange-anchor).
I don't think any of these classes have an Observable that emits the change events so I guess you'd have to use `Subject` or `Observable.create()` to do it yourself.